# Timezones updates on offline devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, time

my question is not platform dependant but would concern any offline device. I recently discovered that timezones are more or less frequently updated, in particular, the DST date might be changed or disabled at any time, even if it's not something usual, it might definitely happen.

When creating offline devices, for example using Raspberry-like boards, the timezones data will never change and will be stuck to the last update the OS received.

Though, giving the user to ability to choose a timezone is something very desirable since it means that he won't have to take care of the DST time change by himself (basically updating the time manually twice a year).

Hence, I'm wondering how to deal with timezones updates on offline devices? (Or should we just give up the idea of timezones with offline devices, and setting up the device to UTC, letting the user change the time by himself ?).

Comment: This is not a security question

Comment: It's been put there mistakenly, migrated now!